# How can we find the downloaded jquery plugin trying to connect to its developers site?

Tags: javascript, security, jquery-plugins

I am usually downloading several jQuery plugings.
How can I check whether the script is stealing any information (such as user cookie, session id..) and sending to its developer's server?

In php, we are checking backdoor scripts by looking for some functions (system, passthru, shell_exec, etc). Is there any such type of function in JavaScript to connect to its developers site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, your first step should be to read the code. There are a number of tell-tale signs you can look for, including looking for URLs in the code, and any encrypted code.

Of course, some code may be too complex to make this a realistic suggestion, particularly if it's been minified and obfuscated, but it should be possible to scan through it. If it is doing anything like this, it'll be using the same functions it uses to communicated with your own site (ie jQuery's ajax functions), so you won't see specific function calls that raise suspicion, but suspect URLs in the code should be checked out, and you should definitely avoid encrypted code (obfuscated is generally okay, but not encrypted).

Secondly, search the internet for other people commenting about the plugin. If there is anything untoward happening, its likely that other people will have noticed it. Avoid using plugins that don't have enough users to get any comments one way or the other.

Finally, use a tool like Firebug to watch for HTTP requests that occur while you're using a site containing the plugin. If it's communicating with base, it can't hide from you; the browser's debugging tools will happily show you what you need to know.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'd recommend checking Firebug first, and *then* reading the code, but nonetheless, great answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do anything else than read the whole code, and check if it is stealing anything.
Another thing you could do, is to search in the codes after words like 'document.cookie' and 'navigator' and other things that are necesary for stealing information.